# How to move between Venice and nearby islands?

Tags: public-transport, italy, islands, venice

How to travel between Venice and other islands, eg. Murano, Saint'Erasmo, La Giudecca? Is there any public transport lines between these islands? And do they come often?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The two main public transportation are [ACTV](http://www.actv.it/en) and [Alilaguna](http://www.alilaguna.it/en).

You have quite a few options

- Murano:
  **from Piazzale Roma or from Venezia Santa Lucia train station**, take the ACTV line 3. The trip takes 20 mins. You could also take line 4.2 but it takes almost 40 mins.
  **From the airport** you can reach Murano in 30 mins using the Alilaguna public transportation.
  **If you are in Venice** it's better to go to "S. Zaccaria" stop, near Piazza San Marco, and catch the ACTV line 4.1, the trip takes around 40 mins. You could also go to "Fondamente Nove" stop and from there you can take line 4.1 or 4.2 and you should be able to reach Murano in 10 mins.
  **From Treporti or Punta Sabbioni or Burano** you can take the line 12.
- Giudecca: **from Piazzale Roma or from the S. Lucia train station** you can take ACTV line 2 or 4.1.
  **If you are in Piazza San Marco**, again, go to "S. Zaccaria" stop and take line 2 o 4.2.
  **From "Zattere" stop** you can take the line 2. There are actually three stops in La Giudecca: "Palanca", "Redentore" e "Zitelle".
- Sant'Erasmo: **From "Fontamente Nove"** stop take the line 13, one every 40 mins during the day and every hour during the night. There are two stops in Sant'Erasmo. The first one is called "Capannone" after about 35 mins. The second one is called "Chiesa" but be aware that, depending on the time of day, you may need to change boat at the first stop.

[From Venezia to Sant'Erasmo Capannone timetable:
4.25- 5.15- 6.05- 6.35 -7.25 -8.05- 8.45 -9.25- 10.25 -11.25 -12.25-13.25 -14.25 -15.25 -16.05 -16.45 -17.25- 18.05 -18.45-19.40 -20.40 -21.40 -22.40- (NOTE: after this you cant reach the second stop "Chiesa") 23.20-0.00-0.55 -1.55 -2.50- 2.57]

[From Sant'Erasmo Capannone to Venezia timetable:
5.22- 6.07- 6.57- 7.27- 8.17- 8.57- 9.55- 10.55- 11.55- 12.55- 13.55- 14.55- 15.55- 16.57-17.37- 18.17- 18.57- 19.37- 20.17- 21.10- 22.10- 23.10- 0.10- 1.21- 2.31- 4.01]

You have [a lot of ticket options](http://www.actv.it/en/movinginvenice/movinginvenice). I strongly suggest you to read that page carefully in order to see what fits best for you. Since you didn't tell much about the details of your trip it's hard to guess what is more convenient for you.

Answer (score 6):

According to the [map of water bus lines](http://www.actv.it/sites/default/files/Mappa_linee_02_04_2012_100x70%20copia%281%29.pdf) (pdf), you can move to all the islands you mentionned, and more (I loved the quietness of San Michele).

The web site of Venice public transportation is [ACTV.it](http://www.actv.it/).